# How to create byte[] with size using reflections?

Tags: java, reflection, size, arrays

**Introduction**:
So, I'm using an API and I need to overwrite 2 100% identical functions, one returning byte[] and one returning short[]. To make sure I don't have to edit everything twice, I want to create a function returning the required one. But to achieve this I would need to create a byte[4096] or a short[4096] which cannot be casted to anything, so I thought about using reflections and check whether a byte[] or a short[] is required. 
**Problem**:
I don't know how to create a fixed-sized byte[] using reflections, so I'm asking this right here. 
**Solution**:

```
Array.newInstance(byte.class, size); // new byte[size];
Array.newInstance(byte.class, size, size); // new byte[size][];
Array.newInstance(byte.class, size1, size2); // new byte[size1][size2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-):

```
Object byteArray = Array.newInstance(byte.class, 4096)
Object shortArray = Array.newInstance(short.class, 4096);
```

You can use the other methods in `Array` to manipulate the array.

Comment: Would I also be able to do this with a definition like `new byte[16][]`?<br>
Which then would be something like `Array.newInstance(byte[].class,?)`

Comment: @LeonKasko: Well that sounds like it, yes - have you tried?